# Data is not showing up in database after "succesful" registration

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

Hey so I've followed a tutorial on how to create a functional registration system with php and all the code seems to work just fine, however the data I input in my registration form doesn't show up in my database even though the script gives me the output that I have successfully registered. Does anyone know a solution to this?

```
<?php
// Connect to the db
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABSE_USER = 'root';
$DATABSE_PASS = '';
$DATABSE_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try to connect
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABSE_USER, $DATABSE_PASS, $DATABSE_NAME);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    //If there is an error stop the script and display the error
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
//check if the data already exists
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
    //Could not get the data that should have been sent
    exit('Please register first');
}
//Submitted registration values are not empty
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    //if empty exit the script
    exit('Please complete the register form');
}
//check if the username has been used already
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    //encrypt password
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

//store the results to be able to check the db
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    //username already exists
    echo 'Username already used';
} else {
    //Insert new account
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
        //hash the password and use password_verify
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $password, $POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'You have succesfully registered, you can now login';
    }}
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    //Something wrong with the sql statement
    echo 'Could not prepare Statement!';
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ask the database...

Comment: How if I may ask?

Comment: read the docu? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php

Comment: @lars Please, don't recommend these functions to new users.

Comment: @Dharman Why not? Whats wrong with them?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz They are useless. You should enable error reporting instead of manually checking each function call. If you have error reporting enable these error messages will be reported to you automatically.

Comment: No, database errors are not reported by PHP, you'd have to explicitly ask for them... or you'd use PDO, it introduced exceptions...

Answer (score -2):

It is very good practise to add error checking to your code when developing. An easy way to this is to add this at the top of your php page inside php code tags to at least echo errors out on your page -

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Your code should look like this, should return a record. If you had error reporting on, it would have told you where the errors are -

```
// Connect to the db
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABSE_USER = 'root';
$DATABSE_PASS = '';
$DATABSE_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try to connect
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABSE_USER, $DATABSE_PASS, $DATABSE_NAME);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    //If there is an error stop the script and display the error
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

//check if the data already exists
if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset(['password']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //Could not get the data that should have been sent
    exit('Please register first');
} else {
    //check if the username has been used already
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
        //encrypt password
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        //username already exists
        echo 'Username already used';
    } else {
        //Insert new account
        if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
            //hash the password and use password_verify
            $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $password, $POST['email']);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo 'You have succesfully registered, you can now login';
        } else {
            echo 'Data not inserted...';
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

$con->close();
```

Comment: I added the error reporting code. It doesn't output anything though. If I delete one of the curly brackets  I then get the parse error of an unexpected ending.

Comment: Use my code above, I have already corrected it.

Comment: The if construct for checking if the username has been used already then doesn't have a closing bracket so I still get the parse error of an unexpected ending and if I add the bracket I'm back at where I started.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please see if this - echo 'Data not inserted...'; - is returned. Also see that I added var_dump for $stmnt, please see what it returns.

Comment: This is what it puts out :
You have succesfully registered, you can now login object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(3) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(1048) ["error"]=> string(29) "Column 'email' cannot be null" ["error_list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(1048) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "23000" ["error"]=> string(29) "Column 'email' cannot be null" } } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "23000" ["id"]=> int(2) }

Comment: Your code is incorrect - too many if statements

Comment: @YourCommonSense, posters code used as above

Comment: But you ventured to fix it.

Comment: Correct, which I do apologise for, will edit code now. @dux, your answer is in the dump, your e-mail has no value - Column 'email' cannot be null

Comment: @dux, I have changed code completely, thank you YourCommonSense, it checks for each return post variable, many if statements removed.

Comment: I changed my code using yours however I now get a Fatal error in line 20:
 Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)